# Attempting to create pageload tooltips based on jQuery validationEngine's look and feel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

My website uses the jQuery.validationEngine plugin to validate user forms.  I really like the look and feel of the tooltips that pop up (ie. they fade in slowly and disappear when the user clicks on them).  [Here is an example](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html) of the validationEngine in use.

I would like to use the same tooltips to show hints or notifications when the user visits certain pages (for example, "you have a new message, click here to view").  So, they're not actually based on validation, but rather the page itself loading.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to call the actual tooltips that the jQuery plugin uses, without having to validate anything.

How can I call the tooltip itself, without validating?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like opening up the source file and checking for words like `tooltip`, `popup`, or `prompt?`. I took a 20 second glance and found `_showPrompt` and `_buildPrompt` which look like what you want.

Comment: I found those functions, but in all honesty, my JavaScript is too basic to understand how to use this without getting through the rest of the "validation" part first.  I'll keep trying.

Comment: Have you thought about making your own plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try the plugin package} {des pack containing 2 plugins for notifications.
1. desNotifiers
2. desToolStip.
3. desWindows.

http://des.delestesoft.com:8080/?go=5